# Plotting DiscretePlot3D with 2nd Form of Sterling Function

Tags: plotting, discrete

I'm trying to figure out how different these two distributions are corresponding to these two functions. What I'm trying to do is to plot them into one DiscretePlot3D graph. However, it doesn't show anything but empty plotting results with three axis.

These two functions are:

[image] and

[image]

And this is my plotting code: (where k, d ∈ [0, 50])

```
(* Before Approximation *)
a[d_, k_] := 
  Sum[t * ((d - t)/2)!*(t/2)!*
    k^((d - t)/2)*(Binomial[d/2, t/2]^2)*(Binomial[k, 2]^(t/2)), {t, 
    0, d}];
b[d_, k_] := Sum[StirlingS2[d, i], {i, 1, k}];
formula[d_, k_] := a[d, k] / b[d, k];

(* After Approximation - In the Paper *)
formula2[d_, k_] := -2 (k^2 + 1)^2 - 
   2 k (d + 1) + (d - 1) (k^2 + 1) + 2 - d;

(* Plotting *)
DiscretePlot3D[formula[d][k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]
DiscretePlot3D[formula2[d][k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]
DiscretePlot3D[{formula[d][k], formula2[d][k]}, {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]
```

Can you guys help me what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: `DiscretePlot3D[formula2[d][k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]` should be written as `DiscretePlot3D[formula2[d, k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]`

Comment: @Richardo. Thanks :) The second plotting works well now. But the first one still doesn't appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Before Approximation*)
a[d_, k_] := 
  Sum[t*((d - t)/2)!*(t/2)!*
    k^((d - t)/2)*(Binomial[d/2, t/2]^2)*(Binomial[k, 2]^(t/2)), {t, 0, d}];
b[d_, k_] := Sum[StirlingS2[d, i], {i, 1, k}];
formula[d_, k_] := a[d, k]/b[d, k];

formula2[d_, k_] := -2 (k^2 + 1)^2 - 2 k (d + 1) + (d - 1) (k^2 + 1) + 2 - d;
```

Looking at the range of the functions:

```
MinMax@N[
    DeleteCases[
     Flatten[
      Table[formula[d, k],
       {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]],
     Indeterminate]] //
 Quiet

(* {0.886227, 3.19956*10^57} *)

MinMax@N[
   Flatten[
    Table[formula2[d, k],
     {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50}]]]

(* {-1.25126*10^7, -1.} *)
```

`formula` needs to be plotted with "Log" scaling

```
DiscretePlot3D[formula[d, k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50},
 Filling -> None,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot3D[formula2[d, k], {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50},
 Filling -> None]
```

[image]

Since `formula` requires "Log" scaling and `formula2` is negative, to combine the plots use `Abs` with `formula2`

```
DiscretePlot3D[
 {formula[d, k], Abs@formula2[d, k]},
 {d, 0, 50}, {k, 0, 50},
 Filling -> None,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
 PlotLegends -> {formula, Abs@formula2}]
```

[image]